# External HDD occasionally getting dropped

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I am using Ubuntu Server 20.04.
I have an external HDD with a single EXT4 partition. It's automounting properly on boot.

Recently I am noticing that the drive occasionally is unmounted by an error:

```
EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #79429633: comm CheckForUpdates: reading directory lblock 0
```

I only started doing this last weekend.
Unsure what could it be or how can I fix it.

What can I do to troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Comment: I think your HDD is failing.

Comment: Yeah me too. I was able to get it working. But lost all data. I’ll start looking at options.